# Qt - Centering a checkbox in a QTable

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtablewidgetitem, qcheckbox

In QtCreater I added a table to my project. in my code I am generating some data to output into the table. I want to add a `QCheckbox` into each row to allow the row to be selected. All the content of the table is aligned left, how do I make only these checkboxes in the first column of every row align to the center?

I'm adding the `QCheckbox` using:

```
ui->data_table->setCellWidget(rowCount,0, new QCheckBox);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually use a layout and a container widget for this. It is an ugly solution, but it works:

```
QWidget * w = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout *l = new QHBoxLayout();
l->setAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter );
l->addWidget( <add your checkbox here> );
w->setLayout( l );
ui->data_table->setCellWidget(rowCount,0, w);
```

So basically you will have:

```
Table Cell -> Widget -> Layout -> Checkbox
```

you'll have to consider it if you will need to access the checkbox through the table.

Comment: It seems like something that should be much easier then that. I was looking through docs for a long time trying to find a function or something that did what I wanted. But what you posted works perfectly, I would of never figured that out on my own though. Thanks!

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, how to get the checkstatus of the checkbox?

Comment: Alignment is perfect here. It's not when using stylesheet proposed by other answers (where checkbox ends up shifted to the right by some pixels).

Answer (score 22):

Two thumbs up for Barry Mavin! You don't even have to subclass.

one line...

```
pCheckBox->setStyleSheet("margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%;");
```

done!!

Answer (score 7):

This is an old post but in fact there is a much easier and lighter way of achieving this, just subclass `QCheckBox` and set the `stylesheet` to

```
margin-left:50%;
margin-right:50%;
```

Comment: Im in PyQt4 and this only works when setting the initial value. That is, if I resize the column it does not continue to center the checkbox, it only centers it when it is first created.

Answer (score 5):

It works for me, but my checkbox is not completely displayed.

To have a complete view of the widget, remove margins in layout :

l->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

Answer (score 2):

As stated in similar question around Stack Overflow, it's currently an open BUG:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-5368

Answer (score 1):

can be center like this too using layout if want to add more customization

```
// Create a widget that will contain a checkbox
 QWidget *checkBoxWidget = new QWidget();
 QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // We declare and initialize the checkbox
 QHBoxLayout *layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // create a layer with reference to the widget
 layoutCheckBox->addWidget(checkBox);            // Set the checkbox in the layer
 layoutCheckBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);  // Center the checkbox
 layoutCheckBox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);    // Set the zero padding

ui->my_table_view->setCellWidget(row_number,column_number, checkBoxWidget);  // set cell widget
```

OR simply add left right margins

```
checkBox->setStyleSheet("margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%;");
```

Comment: For some reason `margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%;` is giving me off-center with respect to the column heading. Any ideas.

Comment: I ended up using the first method which worked correctly without the offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if QT_VERSION < 0x046000
#include <QCommonStyle>
class MyStyle : public QCommonStyle {
public:
  QRect subElementRect(SubElement subElement, const QStyleOption *option, const QWidget *widget = 0) const {
    switch(subElement) {
      case QStyle::SE_CheckBoxIndicator: {
        QRect r = QCommonStyle::subElementRect(subElement, option, widget);
        r.setRect( (widget->width() - r.width())/2, r.top(), r.width(), r.height());
        return QRect(r);
      }
      default: return QCommonStyle::subElementRect(subElement, option, widget);
    }
  }
};
#else
#include <QProxyStyle>
#include <QStyleFactory>
class MyStyle: public QProxyStyle {
public:
  MyStyle():QProxyStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion")) {}
  QRect subElementRect(SubElement subElement, const QStyleOption *option, const QWidget *widget = 0) const {
    switch(subElement) {
      case QStyle::SE_CheckBoxIndicator: {
        QRect r = QProxyStyle::subElementRect(subElement, option, widget);
        r.setRect( (widget->width() - r.width())/2, r.top(), r.width(), r.height());
        return QRect(r);
      }
      default: return QProxyStyle::subElementRect(subElement, option, widget);
    }
  }
};
#endif

QCheckBox *box = new QCheckBox();
box->setStyle(new MyStyle());
```

Answer (score 0):

For the regular rows of data, you can just adjust your model, testing the role in the data method.  This seems to work for me:

```
if(role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
    {
    return(Qt::AlignHCenter); // or AlignCenter - either one works I beleive
    }
```

This does not get solved for the header however - so if you have a header with a checkbox (like select all), that won't be solved.  But this solves the data problem of aligning at least.