# QListWidget inside QGraphicsScene not scrolling text items

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget inside a QGraphicsScene. I add new items with QLineEdit inside. When QListWidget fills and scrollbars are active on the scroll, text does not scroll, current item representation does.

[image]

Complete code Git: [code](https://github.com/pazduha/GrapScene)

EDIT:

I included QCheckBox inside a Horizontal layout to show why I need the `setItemWidget` function.

Comment: Qt 5.3 works well. BTW your code shows the first item at the bottom of list, not 
 top.

Comment: yes that is the problem. I will test with different version than current 5.9.4

Comment: So what's the problem...as you mentioned _text does not scroll_  isn't this? text & scroll both work well, what performance you except?

Comment: Yes, the problem is: If I move the bar the text stays in the same place.

Comment: Test it like this. Press PushButton till u get lots of items and a scrollbar. Name the first item something. Move the scrollbar.

Comment: @pazduha Your code has an error, to correct it changes in mainwindow.h change `void MyGraphicsView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);` to `void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);`, even so I can confirm the bug in Qt 5.10.1

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

The text does not scroll because [setItemWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) is:

> `void QListWidget::setItemWidget(QListWidgetItem *item, QWidget *widget)`
>
> Sets the widget to be displayed in the given item. This function should only be used to display **static content** in the place of
>   a list widget item. If you want to display custom dynamic content or
>   implement a custom editor widget, use QListView and subclass
>   QItemDelegate instead.

it's nothing about `QGraphicsScene`.

**Solution:**

If you want to make the text editable. it's much simpler then you customize the `QItemDelegate`.

First, set the list widget with an edit trigger, tell the widget when to start editing.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ...

    ui->listWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked);
}
```

Then when you create & insert the `QListWidgetItem`, make sure each item is editable.

※Replace you whole `on_pushButton_clicked` function as below:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem("name");
    item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    ui->listWidget->insertItem(ui->listWidget->currentRow() + 1, item);
}
```

Comment: This a solution for this particular problem. The problem is I need to add more to the horizontal layout as shown in the edited code (GIT, edit above). I will look into QListView and QItemDelegate.

Comment: @pazduha For that case, you need to _use QListView and subclass QItemDelegate instead_

Comment: @pazduha If you have multi columns use QTableView  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660292/qt-using-custom-qitemdelegate-for-qtableview

Comment: And if you just want them to display as a list why not simply use QLayout with the scroll bar?

Comment: In my project I use dragDropMode - InternalMove. I want to keep using this, thats why QListView is needed. QTableView would probably not be ok for drag/drop.