# how to align center align a radio button inside a qtable widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I created a following table in `Qt`:
[image]

The radio buttons in the first column are left aligned. I want them to be center aligned. I looked online but I wasn't able to find anything that would explain how to do it. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Do you think it will look better? I think it's best with left alignment, just add some left margin/padding for clearance.

Comment: It really is not me who want's it. It is my boss. Any way to do it without padding. The size of the cell will change and it would be nice if it could align itself automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, I wasn't suggesting padding as a way of centering the item.

Comment: Did you try to put the table into `QHBoxLayout` ? (according to this [qt-centering-a-checkbox-in-a-qtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847928/qt-centering-a-checkbox-in-a-qtable)  and this [qtablewidget-center-checkbox-inside-cell](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.ro/2013/11/qtablewidget-center-checkbox-inside-cell.html))